# How do I make it possible for Admins to match a particular type of users(students) to another type of users (their respective mentors) in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Pls I am quite new here and also, I am new to web development, pardon my unconventional way of asking this question.

I am currently working on a website with laravel 5.6 for a hub. One of the features included is to set up meetings/training online between students and their with their mentors majorly lecturers.

Each student will have to be matched to a given mentor in his/her field.

How do I structure the tables and their relationships?

**What I have done already:**
I created a mentor table and a student's table also, the student's table has a mentor's id field.

I also set up a mentor "has many" relationship to the student's table while the student's table "belong's to" relationship to the mentors table.

I am currently stuck here as I am confused how to make the admin assign students to mentors from the front end.

Your insights and ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you add the code here? It would be a lot easier for us to give advise.

Answer (score 0):

Student should have mentor_id in students database table.
Create a view and assign it to route.
In this view create form with input type text where admin can write mentor id.
Submit form with method post and assign route to action="" attribute.
Connect route with controller function in routes/web.php
Pull input field value from $request in controller function
Assign that value to student object and save in database.